# How to use mktime to change time with miliseconds info. retained?

Tags: awk

for example

I want to add `13.29s` to `2013-4-24 3:10:50.50`

how to handle the milisecond ?

I've tried to use `mktime` and `strftime`, but it seems that can only deal with seconds...

Answer (score 2):

awk is really a powerful tool, but I don't think awk was the best choice here, I would go with `gnu date`.

see the test with your example data:

```
#add 13.29s to date 2013-4-24 3:10:50.50

kent$  date -d'+13.29 second 2013-4-24 3:10:50.50' +"%F %T.%N"
2013-04-24 03:11:03.790000000
```

well I know that there are trailing zeros for nano seconds. but I think it wouldn't be problem for you if you want to remove them.

you can invoke external command from awk, if using awk is a must for you.

Answer (score 0):

Not simple thing to do, but here we go:

```
time="2013-4-24 3:10:50.50"
echo "13.29" | awk '{split(v,a,"[ -:.]");t=mktime(a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6])+(a[7]/100)+$1;print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",t)"."(t-int(t))*100}' v="$time"
2013-04-24 03:11:03.79
```

---

With explanation

```
echo "13.29" | awk '
    {
    split(v,a,"[ -:.]")                                                 # Split the date string into separate parts
    t=mktime(a[1]" "a[2]" "a[3]" "a[4]" "a[5]" "a[6])+(a[7]/100)+$1     # Convert to epoch time and add milliseconds and calcualte the new value
    print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",t)"."(t-int(t))*100              # Convert back to normal time format and print it out
    }
    ' v="$time"                                                         # Read the variable
```

Comment: thank you! so, there is no easy way, and have to add an IF in case for milisecond carry...